# using split in R and then assigning each component to a new vector

Tags: r, split

I have a list of losses experienced by business (identified by unique ID) as follows:

```
Unique company ID   Gross amount
1                   223,220.00
2                   0
3                   386,640.40
4                   19,891.95
1                   0
2                   355,000.00
3                   161,212.13
4                   27,720.00
1                   14,846.00
2                   900,000.00
```

I have used a split the loss data by insurer ID, using the following:

```
individualinsurer <- split(lossdata,lossdata$Unique.ID)
```

I was wondering how I could make each item in the split e.g. `individualinsurer[1]` into a vector. This would help me carry out further statistical analysis on each unique company ID.

Thanks
S

Comment: You have `split` the entire dataset by `Unique.ID`.   I guess you need to `split` the 'Gross_amount' column based on the 'Unique.ID'.  In that case `split(lossdata$Gross_amount, lossdata$Unique.ID)`.  The output will be a `list`.  It is better to keep it in a list rather than having several individual objects in the global environment

Comment: And change the format of the numbers so you can do math operations `lossdata$Gross.amount <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", lossdata$Gross.amount))`

Comment: Thanks Akrun, but I was hoping that the output could be a data frame because I wanted to use a summaryBy to divide the losses further by time of occurrence. Any ideas?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand your new comment as it is different from the description in the post (where you want vectors).  The output from the `split` in your code is a  list of `data.frame`s.  If you wanted to summarise by `UniqueID`, you don't even have to `split`, There are `aggregate`, data.table/dplyr methods which can do it more effficiently

Comment: the summaryBy function requires that the second parameter is a data frame. If I use `summaryBy(Gross.amount # Start.Year, individualinsurer, FUN=SUM)`, since 'individualinsurer` is an output of the split function, I get an error `Error in rep.int("1", nrow(data)) : incorrect type for second argument`. Could you please elaborate on the other aggregate methods? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to summarise the data in many ways. Here are a few examples of common summaries grouped by ID. The sums, averages, and number of observations are shown below.

*(Note: The Data section shows how the numerical column was converted to real numbers able to be calculated.)*

```
library(dplyr)
lossdata %>% group_by(Unique.ID) %>% summarise(sums = sum(Gross.amount),
                                               obs = n(),
                                               avg = mean(Gross.amount))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#
#  Unique.ID       sums obs       avg
#1         1  238066.00   3  79355.33
#2         2 1255000.00   3 418333.33
#3         3  547852.53   2 273926.27
#4         4   47611.95   2  23805.97
```

A `data.table` solution suggested by @akrun:

```
setDT(lossdata)[,list(sums=sum(Gross.amount), obs=.N, avg= mean(Gross.amount)) , Unique.ID]
#   Unique.ID       sums obs       avg
#1:         1  238066.00   3  79355.33
#2:         2 1255000.00   3 418333.33
#3:         3  547852.53   2 273926.27
#4:         4   47611.95   2  23805.97
```

**Data**

```
lossdata <- structure(list(Unique.ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L), Gross.amount = structure(c(5L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
6L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("0", "14,846.00", "161,212.13", "19,891.95", 
"223,220.00", "27,720.00", "355,000.00", "386,640.40", "900,000.00"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Unique.ID", "Gross.amount"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

lossdata$Gross.amount <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", lossdata$Gross.amount))
```